# Typescript syntax for function overloading when using T | undefined

Tags: typescript

Is there an easier way of typing the following function without explicitly writing out all of the overloads?

```js
export function stringifyDate(unformattedDate: Date): string;
export function stringifyDate(unformattedDate: undefined): undefined;
export function stringifyDate(unformattedDate: Date | undefined): string | undefined;
export function stringifyDate(unformattedDate: Date | undefined): string | undefined {
  return unformattedDate
    ? formatISO(unformattedDate, { representation: "date" })
    : undefined;
}
```

Comment: This is the easiest way. Using generics to type conditional return types is really bad for both you and the user of the function. In the body, you'll get strange errors because of conditional types, and for the user, they'll get a strange function signature instead of nice, separate overloads. Also, overloads are arguably easier to understand/maintain/extensible.

Answer (score 0):

If we are going for shortest code possible, then this might be it:

```
export function stringifyDate<T extends Date | undefined>(unformattedDate: T) {
  return (unformattedDate
    ? formatISO(unformattedDate, { representation: "date" })
    : undefined) as T extends Date ? string : undefined
}
```

We can replace the overloads by making the function generic and using a conditional return type.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgGYFcB2BjOBLKaEDOcM2aA5tkgJ4AiAhnCADwAqC4jaAJgQvYwgA%20CdFxBJSILgD4AFOiSwAtg0Zd%20IAFwIWASgQBvYAgQwQcFDHzy0imCrhqNxkwgD8yZQwCSAZQDyNnYOTgwgADSGpiAQZgQgaHAMuGjaAERcYWkIAL66LibaouKSXPp0vGwcCTx8Ye51AkXcJWhSwDnAwEQk5JS0YbJtAO6NILK6%20T2kFNQaNmISbWXdxDP988VLUggVY0IiLdtlQA)

Comment: But then we're "casting" the type with `as`, doesn't that just override the type checking?

Comment: This doesn't return a string when `T` is `Date`.

Comment: @JohanLindskogen - TypeScript can't type check conditional return types anyway.